# Understanding Lists and what did I learn?

Tags: c#, list

I'm including two snippets of code, the first is wrong, the second is right. While I think I understand it may be beneficial for further explanation :) I was confused why, when I created a new SeriesData class, it was, well empty! After all, I clearly added a new Series with a list of two new Games, right???

```
public class SeriesData
{
    // ReSharper disable once FieldCanBeMadeReadOnly.Global
    public List<Series> DivisionSeries;

    public SeriesData()
    {
        this.DivisionSeries = new List<Series>
        {
            new Series
            {
                HomeSeries = new List<Game>(),
                AwaySeries = new List<Game>()
            }
        };

        this.DivisionSeries.ToList().Add(new Series { HomeSeries = new List<Game> { new Game(), new Game() } });
    }
}
```

...and then, proverbial light bulb went on and I realized, the empty Series I was looking at was the one instantiated inside the constructor, and my subsequent addition to DivisionSeries.ToList() resulted in a new list and one not otherwise assigned/reassigned?

```
public class SeriesData
{
    // ReSharper disable once FieldCanBeMadeReadOnly.Global
    public List<Series> DivisionSeries;

    public SeriesData()
    {
        this.DivisionSeries = new List<Series>
        {
            new Series {HomeSeries = new List<Game> {new Game(), new Game()}},
            new Series {AwaySeries = new List<Game> {new Game(), new Game(), new Game()}}
        };
    }
}
```

Perhaps someone would be so kind as to explain more fully what I learned here?

And better yet:

```
    public class SeriesData
{
    // ReSharper disable once FieldCanBeMadeReadOnly.Global
    public List<Series> DivisionSeries;

    public SeriesData()
    {
        this.DivisionSeries = new List<Series>
        {
            new Series {Games = new List<Game> {new Game(), new Game()}, SeriesType = Schedule.SeriesType.Home},
            new Series {Games = new List<Game> {new Game(), new Game(), new Game()}, SeriesType = Schedule.SeriesType.Away}
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: And it has already occurred to me I likely don't need HomeSeries, AwaySeries but perhaps: List<Game> Games and an enumeration type of SeriesType: Home, Away.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: @Jonesopolis Why did the first code snippet result in an empty class? Are you my presumptions correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you are asking,

> why does the first code snippet not result in `DivisionSeries` having two items in it?

You add one item to `DivisionSeries`:

```
this.DivisionSeries = new List<Series>
    {
        new Series
        {
            HomeSeries = new List<Game>(),
            AwaySeries = new List<Game>()
        }
    };
```

then you call `DivisionSeries.ToList()`, and add an item to *that*:

```
this.DivisionSeries.ToList().Add(new Series { HomeSeries = new List<Game> { new Game(), new Game() } });
```

this is the same as:

```
var temp = this.DivisionSeries.ToList();
temp.Add(new Series { HomeSeries = new List<Game> { new Game(), new Game() } });
```

`temp` is a reference to a new object, that happens to be populated with the same items as `DivisionSeries`.  But at that point, `temp` and `DivisionSeries` are two separate references, and adding/removing items from one is independent of the other.

The 'fix' here is to remove the `.ToList()` call, as `DivisionSeries` is already a `List<>`.